# terraform provider aws registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to comment out "random " and rds my tf code and getting the below error
registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random when plan and apply

my tf config is below and using the latest provider this will happen only during the comment out code and plan and apply (as my code contains other vpc and subnets etc which i dont want to destroy and i want to destroy only rds

```
        terraform {
          required_version = "=1.2.2"
          required_providers {
            aws = {
              version = "~> 4.0"
              source  = "hashicorp/aws"
            }
            // null    = {}
            // archive = {}
          }
        }
        
        resource "random_password" "database_password" {
          length  = 16
          special = false
        }
        
        resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "database_password_secret" {
          name        = "_master_password"
          description = "RDS MYSQL database password"
          type        = "SecureString"
          value       = random_password.database_password.result
        }

    resource "aws_db_instance" "this" {
      identifier          = var.identifier_name
      engine              = var.engine_name
      engine_version      = var.engine_version
      port                = var.port
      db_name             = var.db_name
      username            = var.username
      password            = random_password.database_password.result
    }
   $ terraform providers



    resource "aws_db_instance" "this" {
      identifier          = var.identifier_name
      engine              = var.engine_name
      engine_version      = var.engine_version
      port                = var.port
      db_name             = var.db_name
      username            = var.username
      password            = random_password.database_password.result




╷
│





 Error: failed to read provider configuration schema for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random: failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random" to obtain schema: unavailable provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random"
```

Comment: Did you run `terraform init` before running plan?

Answer (score 2):

thanks all i have found the issue, to fix this I need to add below provider

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "2.3.0"
    }
  }
}
```